# Converting utf7 string to iso8859-1

Tags: perl

How can I convert a utf7 string to iso-8859-1 format? I tried the following but it prints the wrong result:

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);
$data ='t+AOQ-m+AOQ- on mit+AOQ- on';
$data = encode("iso-8859-1", decode("utf7", $data));
print $data; #result Tämä on mitä on
```

This prints `tΣmΣ on mitΣ on`, but it should print `Tämä on mitä on`

Comment: maybe u mean `encode('iso-8859-1', decode('utf7', $data));`?

Comment: yes that's i meaning, but this my code is not working

Comment: result to this code is tΣmΣ on mitΣ on, but correct result should be Tämä on mitä on

Comment: Which charset is expected by the terminal? What is reported by `echo $LANG`?

Comment: Andrzej's questions are important. When working with character encoding, take care not to trust the way you are viewing the results. Take a look at the bytes if you can during tests, just to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use Windows and the regional settings are finnish all of them.

Comment: Just curious, what is the notation on line 2, the raw input version? Haven't seen that one before.

Answer (score 5):

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);
$data ='t+AOQ-m+AOQ- on mit+AOQ- on';
$data = encode("iso-latin-1", decode("utf7", $data));
printf "%v02X\n", $data;
```

gives

```
74.E4.6D.E4.20.6F.6E.20.6D.69.74.E4.20.6F.6E
```

which is the iso-latin-1 encoding of

```
tämä on mitä on
```

If you see something other than "tämä on mitä on", it's because the tool you are using to view it is treating it as something other than iso-latin-1.

Do you want iso-latin-1, or do you want it to show correctly in your tool? If it's the latter, use the correct encoding instead of iso-latin-1.

If command-line tool `chcp` returns 437 (for example), you want cp437.

```
use Encode qw(encode decode);
my $raw ='t+AOQ-m+AOQ- on mit+AOQ- on';
my $data = decode("utf7", $raw);
print encode("cp437", "$data\n");
```

or better yet

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(cp437)';
use Encode qw(decode);
my $raw ='t+AOQ-m+AOQ- on mit+AOQ- on';
my $data = decode("utf7", $raw);
print "$data\n";
```